# mathematical operation on each column of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a very large labeled dictionary array dataframe,df of dimension (9  by 4500) with index [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9]. I intend to carry out the following respective mathematical row operation on the dataframe:

mu1=1D1+2D2+3D3+...+nDn                                  # 'n' is the index number

mu2=(1^2)D1+(2^2)D2+(3^2)D3+...+(n^2)Dn                  # 'n' is the index number

Here is the code I implemented but do not get what I expected:

```
##calculating mu1:
n=10
for x in range(1,n):
mu1=df.apply(lambda x:(2*x-1) if x.name in [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9] else x,axis =1)
mu1

## calculating mu2:
n=10
for x in range(1,n):
mu2=df.apply(lambda x:(x**2) if x.name in [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9] else x,axis =1)
mu2
```

I presume my code might be wrong.

Comment: `mu1 = df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x * np.arange(1, 10)))` and `mu2 = df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x * np.arange(1, 10) ** 2))`?

Comment: the equation is not clear to me.  Are you adding 9 rows by 9 columns only (I see your df is 9 rows by 4500 columns)?  
`1D1+2D2+3D3+...+nDn` => `(column 1, D1) + (column 2, D2) ... + (column 9, D9)` like you are adding number diagonally?   nDn and you only have up to D9.  Perhaps the sample input and expected result would help.

Comment: Thank you for the response@CJR. I still got the same problems.

Comment: Thanks for the observation@ Emma. The above-intended operation was supposed to be across the 4500 columns.

Comment: For `mu1`, are you multiplying the 1, 2, 3,...9 to each column's corresponding row and summing each column vertically and separately?  If you can add sample, it is easier for me to follow.